# Select all text on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I saw this the other day online and it intrigued me.  The site had several strings of text for embedding video, pictures, etc.  What was neat was when I hovered over them, all of the text in the text box was selected, making it easier to copy/paste.  I'm curious as to how this was done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery for this.

```
<input onmouseover="this.select()" />
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML

```
<textarea class="auto_select"></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$(".auto_select").mouseover(function(){
 $(this).select();
});
```

Just add the jQuery in your global jQuery library and then add the class on each element that you want to select on hover.

Comment: incredibly simple, yet elegant.  i knew it was probably a jquery one liner.  :)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="Just some text here">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#test').mouseenter(function() {
    this.focus();
    this.select(); 
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5F8Wm/

Comment: looking at this reminds me, in the iteration that i saw they had to have used hover because the text was unselected when the mouse moved outside of the box area.  thanks for remind me :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Oops! Didn't see you wanted jQuery! This is it with no library:

```
var el = document.getElementById("your-textarea");

if (el.addEventListener) el.addEventListener("mouseover",selectText,false);
else if (el.attachEvent) el.attachEvent("onmouseover",selectText);
else el.onmouseover = selectText;

function selectText(){

    this.focus();
    this.select();

}
```

See a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GBgJ9/

Comment: i just figured it was easier with jQuery.  i was mainly just curious how it was done.  thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="this.select();" id="textAreaId" name="textArea"/>
```

You can use this `onmouseover` or `onclick` or anywhere you want. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("textarea").hover(function(){
    $(this).select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$("input").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```